# Interacting with browser in MAUI Blazor hybrid for the purpose of google autenthication

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, blazor, maui, hybrid

I am working on implementing a firebase authentication in a MAUI Blazor hybrid app.

Using the web api wrapped in the popular FirebaseAutenthication.net library.

What I need to do is open a browser window with google consent screen and capture the url it redirects to.

```cs
@inject NavigationManager navmanager;

        var client = new FirebaseAuthClient(config);

        var userCredential = await client.SignInWithRedirectAsync(FirebaseProviderType.Google, async uri =>
        {
            navmanager.NavigateTo(uri);


            //return credential
        });
```

This works fine but I am not sure how to interact with browser at all after it has been opened.
Any tips please?

Edit:
I think i'm going to try something with JS interop. There must be a way to capture redirect event.

```cs
var userCredential = await client.SignInWithRedirectAsync(FirebaseProviderType.Google, async uri =>
        {
            string credential = "";
            
            async Task OpenWindow()
            {
                await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("authURI", uri);
            }

            await OpenWindow();

            //wait for redirect

            


            return credential;
        });
```

```js
function authURI(uri) {
    var newWindow = window.open(uri);
    console.log(newWindow);
```

So that doesnt work and prints null to console

Answer (score 1):

`WebAuthenticator` is a good choice to get the access token from the webpage. The API consists mainly of a single method `AuthenticateAsync` which takes two parameters: The first uri should be used to start the web browser flow. For the second uri, which you expect the flow to ultimately call back to can be able to be handleed because you have registered the firebase.
Here is the sample:

```
var authResult = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(
        new Uri("https:"),
        new Uri("myapp://"));

var accessToken = authResult?.AccessToken;
```

Comment: Cant really check it atm because WebAutenticator is broken on Windows. But I've found a potential solution involving listening to response and getting redirect url from there. I'll post here once it works.